# JS авто. замена текста в текстовом поле

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте я новичок в JS, не подскажите как реализовать такую идею. Есть 1но поле для текста, 2 кнопки переключения раскладки иностранного алфавита, как соединить 2 кнопки с 1ним полем для текста  при нажатии на кнопку будет вводится своя раскладка.

```
   <input id="" name="results" type="text" autofocus>

   <button type="submit">English</button>
   <button type="submit">Russian</button>
   <script type="text/javascript">

     document.getElementById('english').addEventListener('input',function(n){
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('a').join('а');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('i').join('и');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('u').join('у');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('e').join('э');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('o').join('о');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('k').join('к');
});

document.getElementById('russian').addEventListener('input', function(e){
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('а').join('a');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('и').join('i');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('у').join('u');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('э').join('e');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('о').join('o');
 n.target.value = n.target.value.split('к').join('k');
 });
 </script>
```

Так же мне интересно можно ли заменить такой громоздкий код как

```
  e.target.value = e.target.value.split('и').join('i');
```

на более легкую версию, а то если алфавит будет из 33х строк такой длинны то такой код будет слишком громоздкий. Или возможно такие вещи делаются не через split? Мне главное что бы при введении текста буквы менялись сразу автоматически например "i" на "и"　и так далее.

Answer (score 1):

Конечно же это делается с помощью [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
function translit(lang){
  const matrix = [["щ","shh"],["ш","sh"],["ч","ch"],["ц","cz"],["ю","yu"],["я","ya"],["ё","yo"],["ж","zh"],["ъ","``"],["ы","y'"],["э","e`"],["а","a"],["б","b"],["в","v"],["г","g"],["д","d"],["е","e"],["з","z"],["и","i"],["й","j"],["к","k"],["л","l"],["м","m"],["н","n"],["о","o"],["п","p"],["р","r"],["с","s"],["т","t"],["у","u"],["ф","f"],["х","x"],["ь","`"]];

  let text = input.value;
  matrix.forEach(repl => text = text.replace(repl[(lang === 'ru')%2 ], repl[(lang === 'eng')%2]));
  input.value = text;
}
```

```html
<input id="input" value="Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок, да выпей же чаю!" />
<button onclick="translit('eng')">English</button>
<button onclick="translit('ru')">Russian</button>
```

Если замены у вас строго 1 к 1 символу, то можно сделать так (или 1 к нескольким, но только в одну сторону будет работать):

```js
const ru_en = {"щ":"shh","ш":"sh","ч":"ch","ц":"cz","ю":"yu","я":"ya","ё":"yo","ж":"zh","ъ":"``","ы":"y'","э":"e`","а":"a","б":"b","в":"v","г":"g","д":"d","е":"e","з":"z","и":"i","й":"j","к":"k","л":"l","м":"m","н":"n","о":"o","п":"p","р":"r","с":"s","т":"t","у":"u","ф":"f","х":"x","ь":"`"}
input.onkeypress = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    input.value += ru_en[String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode)] || String.fromCharCode(e.which || e.keyCode);
}
```

```html
<input id="input" />
```

Comment: Спасибо за направление, только мне сей равно не понятно как мне  запихнуть это в 2 функции и соединить с кнопками button, и при нажатии на кнопку English или Russian в текстовом поле будут происходить изменения, при набирании в него текста пользователями.

Comment: @Vitalii обновил ответ

Comment: Почему text константа? :)

Comment: @Duoxx потому что после объявления эта переменная не изменяется

Comment: Я понимаю, но почему не переменная

Comment: А зачем делать переменной константу?

Comment: Так авто замены то нету, нажатие на кнопку по идеи не делает перевод а меняет раскладку. Но сей равно спасибо дальше .join я попробую впихнуть сам. Мне главное что бы при введении текста буквы менялись сразу автоматически например "i" на "и"　и так далее. :)

Comment: @Vitalii обновил ответ. Во втором снипетте теперь только английскими символами (либо напрямую, либо транслитом если русская раскладка)

Comment: Очень неудобно транслитом печатать) все время пальцы на английские символы жмут

Comment: Во втором снипетте ошибки :)

Comment: @Vitalii Какой у вас браузер? Вероятно не chrome, а второй сниппет вероятно не кроссбраузерный, я угадал?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox на хроме работает